Passing Blazor Component Variable Scope
I have a Blazor Component (.razor file) that has an object of type Product. The Object is passed in as a parameter and is correct correct at the top but inside of the modal, the value of Product is always the first item in my database. I was wondering how I can get the value to carry over to my modal. The full component is below and I am using .NET 8.
@using InventoryWebApp.Models.Entity
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        @if (Product != null)
        {
            <p class="card-text">Category:  @Product.Category</p>
            <p class="card-text">Quantity:  @Product.Quantity</p>
            <p class="card-text">Price:    $@(Product.Price.HasValue ? Product.Price.Value.ToString("F2") : "N/A")</p>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#request-purchase-card">
            Request Purchase
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="request-purchase-card">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">@Product?.DisplayName</div>
            <div class="modal-body form-group">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <label for="quantity" class="mx-2">Quantity</label>
                    <button @onclick="() => QuantityToOrder--" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="subtract">-</button>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control mx-2" id="quantity" style="width: 4rem;" value="@QuantityToOrder">
                    <button @onclick="() => QuantityToOrder++" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="add">+</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-primary">Request Item</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Product? Product { get; set; }

    private int quantityToOrder;
    public int QuantityToOrder
    {
        get => quantityToOrder;
        set => quantityToOrder = Math.Clamp(value, 0, 100);
    }
}


what you mean by carry over to my modal?

So the product variable is passed in as a paramater, and displays the right product, but once it leave that first div the value of Product is set to the first Product in the DB. So its like the scope ends at the div or somethiing.

ist that all the code you have in @code or is it just an stripped version? I'm assuming that maybe a parent component is triggering a state change.  did you set a breakpoint on Product set; to debug when the first product is passed in?

@gsharp That is all of the code,  its a new project and I am just trying to understand how they work together. The only other code is the component that passes the product param in, which when it comes into this component it is correct  for Product.Category, quantity and price. However the modal only displays the first Prodcut in the database (which is just a Json for now). What I mean by that is that Product.DisplayName is always "HP Elitebook G9" which is the first item. However if I output the name in the top section, it shows the correct name. Its the same variable so just confused.

If Product is changing when you open the dialog then it's likely the parent is updating the value in a render event.  Without more code or a [MRE] it's hard to tell.  There's nothing in the code you've presented to suggest the behaviour you are reporting.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I agree that it seems like I would be changing the value elsewhere, but I'm don't believe I am. I here iis a repo with all of the code if you don't mind taking a look:
https://github.com/LeeMclafferty/InventoryWebApp

All of your dialogs have the same id i.e. request-purchase-card  As you're using the Bootstrap JS code to open and close the dialog, the code always opens the first instance of the x instances you create.
You can make it work by using a unique id for each modal:
    <div class="card-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="@($"#{_id}")">
            Request Purchase
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="@_id">
//....

@code {
    [Parameter] public Product? Product { get; set; }
    private string _id = $"modal-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}";

//....
{

However, you should consider using one of the Blazor [no JS] modal implementations.  They are simpler to use and have async open/close functionality.  Search Blazor Modal Dialog.  You'll find several implementations (including one of mine!).
